# transaction will fail

Tags: contract-development

I'm also bumping up against the "It seems this transaction will fail" error message when trying to deploy the "MyAdvancedToken" contract from the official ethereum website.  I updated a little bit of code to deal with "throw" being deprecated as well as having the token constructor return "payable" but I'm still not able to get this puppy to deploy.  When I go ahead and do the "send transaction" the contract gets created but there is no data associated with it and I never see it in my contracts section of the ethereum wallet.  The code I have for the contract is below.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;
contract owned {
    address public owner;

    function owned() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner {
        require (msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner {
        owner = newOwner;
    }
}

contract tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData); }

contract token {
    /* Public variables of the token */
    string public standard = 'Token 0.1';
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint8 public decimals;
    uint256 public totalSupply;

    /* This creates an array with all balances */
    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;

    /* This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients */
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

    /* Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract */
    function token(
        uint256 initialSupply,
        string tokenName,
        uint8 decimalUnits,
        string tokenSymbol
        ) payable {
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = initialSupply;              // Give the creator all initial tokens
        totalSupply = initialSupply;                        // Update total supply
        name = tokenName;                                   // Set the name for display purposes
        symbol = tokenSymbol;                               // Set the symbol for display purposes
        decimals = decimalUnits;                            // Amount of decimals for display purposes
    }

    /* Send coins */
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) {
        require (balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);           // Check if the sender has enough
        require (balanceOf[_to] + _value >= balanceOf[_to]); // Check for overflows
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;                     // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;                            // Add the same to the recipient
        Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);                   // Notify anyone listening that this transfer took place
    }

    /* Allow another contract to spend some tokens in your behalf */
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value)
        returns (bool success) {
        allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        return true;
    }

    /* Approve and then communicate the approved contract in a single tx */
    function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData)
        returns (bool success) {    
        tokenRecipient spender = tokenRecipient(_spender);
        if (approve(_spender, _value)) {
            spender.receiveApproval(msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData);
            return true;
        }
    }

    /* A contract attempts to get the coins */
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        require (balanceOf[_from] >= _value);                 // Check if the sender has enough
        require (balanceOf[_to] + _value >= balanceOf[_to]);  // Check for overflows
        require (_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);   // Check allowance
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                          // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;                            // Add the same to the recipient
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    /* This unnamed function is called whenever someone tries to send ether to it */
    function () {
        revert();     // Prevents accidental sending of ether
    }
}

contract WOLFFE is owned, token {

    uint256 public sellPrice;
    uint256 public buyPrice;

    mapping (address => bool) public frozenAccount;

    /* This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients */
    event FrozenFunds(address target, bool frozen);

    /* Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract */
    function WOLFFE(
        uint256 initialSupply,
        string tokenName,
        uint8 decimalUnits,
        string tokenSymbol
    ) token (initialSupply, tokenName, decimalUnits, tokenSymbol) {}

    /* Send coins */
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) {
        require (balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);           // Check if the sender has enough
        require (balanceOf[_to] + _value >= balanceOf[_to]); // Check for overflows
        require (!frozenAccount[msg.sender]);                // Check if frozen
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;                     // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;                            // Add the same to the recipient
        Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);                   // Notify anyone listening that this transfer took place
    }


    /* A contract attempts to get the coins */
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        require (!frozenAccount[_from]);                        // Check if frozen            
        require (balanceOf[_from] >= _value);                 // Check if the sender has enough
        require (balanceOf[_to] + _value >= balanceOf[_to]);  // Check for overflows
        require (_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);   // Check allowance
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                          // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;                            // Add the same to the recipient
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function mintToken(address target, uint256 mintedAmount) onlyOwner {
        balanceOf[target] += mintedAmount;
        totalSupply += mintedAmount;
        Transfer(0, this, mintedAmount);
        Transfer(this, target, mintedAmount);
    }

    function freezeAccount(address target, bool freeze) onlyOwner {
        frozenAccount[target] = freeze;
        FrozenFunds(target, freeze);
    }

    function setPrices(uint256 newSellPrice, uint256 newBuyPrice) onlyOwner {
        sellPrice = newSellPrice;
        buyPrice = newBuyPrice;
    }

    function buy() payable {
        uint amount = msg.value / buyPrice;                // calculates the amount
        require (balanceOf[this] >= amount);               // checks if it has enough to sell
        balanceOf[msg.sender] += amount;                   // adds the amount to buyer's balance
        balanceOf[this] -= amount;                         // subtracts amount from seller's balance
        Transfer(this, msg.sender, amount);                // execute an event reflecting the change
    }

    function sell(uint256 amount) {
        require (balanceOf[msg.sender] >= amount );        // checks if the sender has enough to sell
        balanceOf[this] += amount;                         // adds the amount to owner's balance
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= amount;                   // subtracts the amount from seller's balance
        if (!msg.sender.send(amount * sellPrice)) {        // sends ether to the seller. It's important
            revert();                                         // to do this last to avoid recursion attacks
        } else {
            Transfer(msg.sender, this, amount);            // executes an event reflecting on the change
        }               
    }
}
```

Comment: I figured it out.  The transfer function I had needed to return 'payable' as well

Comment: Hi @Josh - could you add an answer explaining in a bit more detail what you needed to do? It might help others in future, and it'll stop this question going stale and unanswered :-)